# How to use model on view in Orchard for TextBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, orchardcms

I have model ReservationViewModel for use on view. There are set validation information etc. How to use it on view in methods like TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)? Exist any options how to declare model on OrchardCMS view(not in editorTempates but in client side)? If I understand good, orchard use in display method some contentshapes not model.

Thanks for some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shapes are view models, only, they're dynamic objects. The strongly-typed, Lambda-based Html helpers don't work with dynamic objects, which are not strongly-typed. Use the weakly-typed Html helpers. In your example, that would be `Textbox("FirstName")`.

Strongly-typed view models however are perfectly fine in Orchard. In order to determine how to use them in your particular use case, I'd need to know whether you're creating the view model in a controller action or in a driver.